# Why is 64 bit OS version packaged with both 32 and 64 bit libraries?

Tags: linux, libraries, 32-vs-64-bit

I installed SuSE 64 bit version, and i saw it has libraries (Samba), installed with both 32 and 64 bit versions.

We used to upgrade only the 64 bit version of libraries of Samba in our software package, leaving 32 bit untouched.

We are now thinking to totally remove the 32 bit version of libraries from the OS. Will it have any functional impact?

Please suggest.

Comment: Anyone wishing to have a good time as he/she  ponders exactly this topic, should read http://lwn.net/Articles/190847/, a nice article predicting (in 2006) the death of the multiarch era. The writer is quite the opposite of a noob, yet his prediction did not quite turn out to be ok.

Comment: Are you planning on removing *all* 32-bit libraries or just Samba ones? Normally the package manager will take care of dependencies and warn you if anything on your system is relying on the libraries you are trying to remove.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Only the 32 bit Samba, not all

Comment: I'd suggest testing it first. It might also be useful to say which libraries specifically, in case someone has had experience with this. Also, which version of suse?

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that some programs, even on 64-bit installs, are still linked with 32-bit versions of Samba. I'm not sure if it changed, but eg. Wine was 32-bit not so long ago. I suspect there are others.